# Avoid Server restart after publishing resource in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, webserver

i am using eclipse server to the publish my web application to my local tomcat server.Whenever i modify
java or non java resource, it gets published to server(as i have selected automatically publish when resource change).But problem
is as soon as resource is published, server gets restarted which i want to avoid as it takes ample amount of time. How to avoid server restart ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for hot deployment?

Heres a good tutorial I seen a while ago http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks i was looking exactly like this.

Answer (score 0):

***Whenever you change your code***, Automatically eclipse detect your source has modified, and ***start redeploying your actual code into server***. So that Tomcat server is restarting in a particular time interval.

You can configure tomcat for reload automatically, configure the attribute reloadable to true of the Context.

For do Tomcat 7 you must do.

Edit CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml
Change:

```
<Context>
```

For:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Where CATALINA_HOME is your tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

clicks on the “`Module`” view, make sure “`Auto Reload`” is “`Disabled`“. Default is enabled. It will stop the auto restart.

To do it in one go for all modules

In server options, uncheck option `Modules auto reload by default`

Also have a look at [Stop Eclipse restarting my web app on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712232/stop-eclipse-restarting-my-web-app-on-file-save)